# With react-ace I would like add mode php which is currently not supported

Tags: reactjs, ace-editor, react-ace

For https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace

I know the documentation does not support mode php - but I would like to use that.

Is there a way to include that steps to add it? https://ace.c9.io seems to support it - is there an easy way to add additional modes / themes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi brace package has support for php mode too...

[List of supported mode for brace(ace-editor) reference](https://github.com/thlorenz/brace/tree/master/mode)

```
import React from 'react'
import AceEditor from 'react-ace'

import 'brace/mode/php'
import 'brace/snippets/php';
import 'brace/theme/tomorrow'

const MyEditor = () => {
 return (
   <AceEditor
     name="my-editor"
     mode="php"
     theme="tomorrow"
     value=""
     width="100%"
     height="500px" />
 )
}

export default MyEditor
```